# GitLab CI failing due to "jobs config should contain at least one visible job"

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline, .net-6.0

I am attempting to setup a pipeline for a .NET 6 project to just run some unit tests. I have a separate project in the same repository (also .NET 6) using xUnit for a unit testing framework. It seems that no matter what I try to change in my *.gitlab-ci.yml* file, I get the same error from the pipeline job. The error I'm seeing is this: [GitLab pipeline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv9M7.png)

When putting my configuration into GitLab's CI Lint tool, it tells me the yml is valid.

Here is my configuration:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - build
  - test

job_compile:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - "dotnet restore"
  script:
    - "dotnet build --no-restore"

job_run_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "dotnet test --no-restore"
```

I am having trouble finding the issue here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around with this issue, I have come to a solution.

I had originally wrote this file using VSCode, then publishing to GitLab. I finally read somewhere that I really should have been using GitLab's CI/CD editor (in browser). I opened my existing config in GitLab's CI/CD editor, added one space to the end and then removed it. The editor now claimed that my configuration was valid (even though there was no net change). I committed my "change", and the jobs ran flawlessly.

Comment: had a similar issue. I copied an existing .yml ci file and replaced the content and it worked fine. I then compared the broken and working files and noticed that the difference was the encoding: UTF-8 BOM (broken) vs UTF-8 (working)